# How to find the document by custom field name (not _id) in the mongodb using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have documents in my mongodb like this

```
{
        "song_Name": "akon-Breakdown",
        "album_Name": "Akon collection",
        "release_date": "2019-09-11T18:30:00.000Z",
        "description": "akon popular collection",
        "song_image_uri": "http://neptechco.com/assets/akon-breakdown.jpg",
        "song_uri": "https://monal.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Audio/English/collection/akon-Breakdown.mp3",
        "home_featured": true,
        "_id": "5d7980c1d043b70dfd2dcfc5",
        "song_main_category": "English"
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Now i am creating an API for finding the song by its song_uri not by its  id to check if there is any duplicate song posted.

But i think this is going to be so complex.

If there is any other suggestion to find the song by its song_uri, I would really appreciate the suggestions.

I can do it by finding by id and searching its song_uri in findall API

here is my code how i am trying

```js
let getMusicInfo = (req, res) => {
    const songurl = req.params.songId;
    Music.find({ _id: songurl })
        .exec()
        .then(result => {
            if (result.length > 0) {
                let currentSongURL = result.song_uri;
                Music.find()
                    .exec()
                    .then(docs => {
                        for (let i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
                            if (currentSongURL == docs[i].song_uri) {
                                console.log("duplicate")
                            } else {
                                res.status(200).json(result);
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        res.status(500).json({
                            error: err
                        });
                    })
            }
        })

}
```

I expect the output to send me duplicate message when the song_uri is already present in any of the document in mogodb.

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass `song_uri` in query param of GET, as you're not able to make it POST api(ideally url can be passed as string in post request body & be retrieved as `req.body.songURL`, url in path param of GET is not that feasible) - So if considering query param then you don't need to make two find calls to DB - Once you get the result of .find() if you get more than one record then that `song_uri` has duplicate records in DB (We're doing exact match for a string, not a partial search & also if this happens often try to have an index on the field & make that text field as text index), Below is sample code - Please try this :

```
let getMusicInfo = (req, res) => {
    //const songurl = req.params.songId;
    // let's say you get song_uri in songURL
    Music.find({ song_uri: req.query.songURL })
        .exec()
        .then(result => {
            if (result.length > 1) {
                console.log("duplicate")
                res.status(409);
            } else {
                res.status(200).json(result);
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        })

}
```

else if you don't have `song_uri` value & only have `_id` of a song & still need to find duplicates on `song_uri`(no change in your requirement) then try this, this helps to avoid two DB calls, check on performance of this query :

```
let getMusicInfo = (req, res) => {
const songID = req.params.songId;
Music.aggregate([{ $project: { song_uri: 1 } },
{ $group: { _id: '$song_uri', doc: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } },
{ $match: { 'doc._id': songID } },
{ $project: { songUrlsCount: { $size: '$doc' } } }])
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
        if (result.length && result.songUrlsCount > 1) {
            console.log("duplicate")
            res.status(409);
        } else {
            res.status(200).json(result);
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    })
```

}

Or by doing two DB calls(Only change below is instead doing .find() on entire collection & iterating changed to specific thing i.e; _id, no change in your requirement) :

```
let getMusicInfo = (req, res) => {
    const songurl = req.params.songId;
    Music.find({ _id: songurl })
        .exec()
        .then(result => {
            if (result.length > 0) {
                let currentSongURL = result.song_uri;
                Music.find({ song_uri: currentSongURL })
                    .exec()
                    .then(result => {
                        if (result.length > 1) {
                            console.log("duplicate")
                            res.status(409);
                        } else {
                            res.status(200).json(result);
                        }
                    }).catch(err => {
                        res.status(500).json({
                            error: err
                        });
                    })
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        })

}
```

Please consider this as basic structure, Refactor & think through error scenarios as well..

Comment: @Lauren : So, Do you get song_uri in request or not ?

Comment: no i am not getting song_uri in request,

I think this is wrong way to do it 

http://localhost:3000/api/v1/musics/https://monal.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Audio/English/collection/akon-Breakdown.mp3

Comment: how do i sent song_uri in the request?

Comment: @LaurenSofe : you can do that in the body of POST request(if you can make ur api as POST) and read it like req.body.songUrl

Comment: but this is a check method for duplicate entry in mongodb. It should be get which I will be using in many operation like dbAddedStatus.

Comment: @LaurenSofe : So first you need to retrieve doc by _id and then check for song_uri if it's duplicated or not !! meanwhile basically you can replace second find() in your code with .find() in my code..

Comment: here i am sending song_uri in body and checking for it but its not working for wrong song_uri
```js
let getMusicInfo = (req, res) => {
    const songurl = req.body.song;
    req.params.songId = songurl
    Music.find({ songId: req.params.songId })
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
        if (result.length > 0) {
            console.log("already added")
            // res.status(409);
        } else {
            console.log("not added")
            res.status(200).json(result);
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
 });})}
```

Comment: @LaurenSofe : I think you're very confused in coding here- above code has a lot of issues(You don't need those many assignments), Can you confirm are you making it POST request or you want it to be GET ? also you've .find({songId:req.params.songId}) - you can't do this as your documents doesn't have field songId !! Even in GET do you've a chance of sending song_uri value or not ? Or do you only have _id of song every-time you use this API ?

Comment: i am doing this as GET, and i am using songId because in my route, i have defined as GET method with songid. my song_uri consist complete LINK so if I send song_uri its wrong. 
I am expecting: send the song_uri and get the document if present. or by any method get the status that song_uri is already present in the mongodb collection.

Comment: Then how can i do this?

Comment: @LaurenSofe : Status in the sense whether it's already there or not ? So all you need is to find if a song_uri is duplicated or not using _id(you can't pass song_uri, as you don't have it while sending request - my thing is if you can pass song_uri then you would avoid two DB calls, if you want instead of POST you can pass it as query param in GET as well) of a song thru GET API ?

Comment: can you show me the sample code ? how can i do this?

Comment: @LaurenSofe : Let's say if your endpoint looks like this GET localhost:3000/api/v1/musics?songURL='https...' then you'll do .find({song_uri : req.query. songURL})

Comment: this is my router ```app.get(`${baseUrl}/:songurl`, musicController.getMusicInfo);```  and in this url is need to be send. is it required to modify.

Comment: Keep it same, now access like this localhost:3000/api/v1/musics?songURL='https...' & replace your func with this ::::>   let getMusicInfo = (req, res) => {
    Music.find({ song_uri: req.query.songURL })
        .exec()
        .then(result => {
            if (result.length > 1) {
                console.log("duplicate")
                res.status(409);
            } else {
                res.status(200).json(result);
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        })

}

Comment: its just returning me complete docs from the mongodb collection (as like GET) POSTMAN URL
```localhost:3000/api/v1/musics?songURL='https://monal.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Audio/English/collection/akon-Breakdown.mp3'```. I tried giving console in function. it not even going into the getMusicInfo()

Comment: yes, they all are returning me the complete doc of collection.

Comment: @LaurenSofe : It shouldn't be the case, Did you try aggregate? Also can you console.log and check what you're getting while retrieving songID

Comment: aggregate function gives me empty array. however, console.log(req.params) gives me proper sent songID.

Comment: @LaurenSofe : Did you make songID as ObjectId before making db call ? Something like ObjectId (songID), if it's going to else block then this might be the case first try any query in DB and then in code..